# get current system time in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, datetime, broadcastreceiver

I am using below code to get time in `BroadcastReceiver` on call performed but I'm always getting the same value after making an outgoing call. Getting time with this code works well when used with `Activity` but it's throwing same value in BroadcastReceiver.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmmss");
    String time= s.format(new Date());  
    System.out.println(time);
}
```

#### Receiver

```
<receiver android:name="com.pairdroid.Information.OutCallLogger" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I think we need more infos about the symptoms and the exact problem (logcat maybe)

Answer (score 1):

Your time format string is wrong try to replace with this :

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
```

Comment: Why do you need `StringBuilder` here? Plain `String` object has to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String format = "HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
String callstarttime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
Toast.makeText(context, callstarttime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```